# Controller not getting session object

Tags: c#, asp.net, owin

I'm working on an existing web application, and in the controller my `HttpContext.Current.Session` variable is null. I've tracked this down to being due to the `HttpContext.Current.Handler` being a `System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler` which doesn't implement `IRequiresSessionState`, but I don't know how to go about changing the handler to one that does, or if that's even advisable. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is your intention to use session in mvc application?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya It's a fork of a legacy application where we're trying to refactor to use IOC and true MVC. I'm trying to make as few changes to the legacy code as possible because we'd like the new API code and the legacy code to be able to coexist while we slowly rebuild. I've managed to refactor most of the problematic parts, but this one section is stashing information in the session and it's far too deep to easily be refactored out.